# Do I need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) for V21 styles too?

Tags: android, material-design

Should my values-v21 folder contain reference to Theme.Appcompat when using Material Design theme?
My API min is 9 and my target API is 21.

I have the following:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

values\styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">    
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
</resources>
```

values-v21\styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

But I get

```
 ...You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

and  I have extended my   `Activity` with `ActionBarActivity`

I mainly followed the following video http://youtu.be/h57QpXp2TRg

Comment: This gist can help you: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/lollipop-release/v7/appcompat/THEMES.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was working in the video that I followed because the instructor was not using a lollipop emulator but a lower version. The next video in the series explained the problem. http://youtu.be/hrlGVU8z7zc

The correct definitions should be:

values-v21\styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
</resources>
```

values\styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">    
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to separate between API versions

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    // Do something for Lollipop and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before Lollipop
}
```

If you then create separate layouts for API 21 without Appcompat you won't need the reference.

Otherwise you will still use Appcompat which requires the use of Theme.Appcompat